# Cross referencing part of rows from two 2D arrays with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have two arrays using NumPy that look like this:

```py
A = np.array([[ 3,  1, 10],
              [ 4,  2, 20],
              [ 2,  0, 30],
              [-1,  1, 20],
              [-1, -2, 30],
              [ 1, -3, 40]])

B = np.array([[-1.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356],
              [ 2.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
              [-1.        , -2.        ,  2.23606798],
              [ 3.        ,  1.        ,  3.16227766],
              [ 1.        , -3.        ,  3.16227766],
              [ 4.        ,  2.        ,  4.47213595]])
```

Now what I am trying to do is cross reference both arrays to produce an array that looks like this:

```py
C = np.array([[-1,  1, 20],
              [ 2,  0, 30],
              [-1, -2, 30],
              [ 3,  1, 10],
              [ 1, -3, 40],
              [ 4,  2, 20]])
```

This new array is created by using the sorted order of array B (by the last column) and finding the corresponding first 2 values from the row in B, somewhere in a row from A and replacing the 3rd element in that row with the value from A.

I am thinking ideally a row conditional to check whether the first 2 elements in a row from B are anywhere in A. If they are, create a vector (or append a new array) with those 2 values with the third value from the row found in A. I do not know how to do row conditionals without referencing the entire row (in this case we only want the first 2 elements to compare) which is my current predicament.

I've tried something that looks like this:

```
c = (a[:1]==b[:1]).all(1).any()
```

but it returns false as in not a single row was found that had similar values. I'm not sure where I am wrong or how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = A[:,:-1] == B[:,:-1,None,None]
idx = np.where(temp[:,0,:,0] * temp[:,1,:,1])[1]
out = np.hstack([B[:,:-1], A[idx,-1].reshape((-1, 1))])
```

The first lines creates a 6x2x6x2 array. `temp[:,0,:,0]` effectively tells you for each row of each of the two arrays (6x6) whether the value of A in the first column is the same as the value of B in the first column. Multiplying that with `temp[:,1,:,1]` gives you a 6x6 matrix where the values in both columns are the same and you can extract that row index with `np.where()`. Printing `idx` shows you

```
array([3, 2, 4, 0, 5, 1], dtype=int64)
```

This means that `[-1, 1]` from B is found in row 3 of A, `[2, 0]` in row 2, etc. The last line extracts the relevant column from A in the desired order and converts it to a "column vector" so you can combine it with B.